# Create a binary file in java

Tags: java, file, io, binary, output

These are the related questions that might cause my question to be closed, even though I specify another question:

- [Java: How to write binary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895123/java-how-to-write-binary-files) -> Doesn't really cover the point that I am talking about
- [create a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255747/create-a-binary-file) -> Absolutely doesn't cover the point
- [Editing a binary file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039403/editing-a-binary-file-in-java) -> They are talking about offsets and stuff, when I just need to write the data and stop
- [Binary files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555444/binary-files-in-java) -> Vague.

And now to the point. I've got a file with a specific extension, to be more exact it's `.nbs`. I want to create a file and then write the specific data to it.

That might have sounded vague so let me show you the code I have started with.

```
try {
    File bpdn = new File(getDataFolder() + "song.nbs");
    if (!bpdn.exists()) {
        bpdn.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(bpdn);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'll provide you even more details. So I've got a `song.nbs` file that I have created in the past, for myself. And now, whenever a person runs my application, I want it so there's a new `song.nbs` file with the exact contents of a file that I have on my PC right now. Therefore, I need to somehow get the bytes of my existing `song.nbs` and then copy and paste them in my Java application... or is it the way? I neither know how to get the bytes of my own file right now, nor do I know how to write them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a *resources* folder. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15749192/9997212).

Assuming your project structure is

```
ProjectName/src/main/java/Main.java
```

you can create a *resources* folder inside *main/*:

```
ProjectName/src/main/java/Main.java
ProjectName/src/main/resources/
```

Move your *song.nbs* you want to read inside *resources/*:

```
ProjectName/src/main/java/Main.java
ProjectName/src/main/resources/song.nbs
```

Now, get the `InputStream` of *song.nbs* stored there:

```java
final ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
final InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("song.nbs");
```

Then, write this input stream to your new file:

```java
final File bpdn = new File(getDataFolder() + "song.nbs");
if (!bpdn.exists()) bpdn.createNewFile();
final FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(bpdn);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood. I can't input anything. I just have a file that I want to clone and create whenever a user starts my application. I think I came up with a solution though

Comment: I think *you* didn't understand my answer. Just put the file A you want to copy in the *resources* folder, get its bytes using `InputStream`, create the file B you want to receive the copy and write the original file bytes to it using `OutputStream`.

Comment: enzo, perhaps you can explain that the resource file will be (should be) compiled into the application's JAR file and won't need to be distributed separately.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The file you want to copy will be available to be read using `ClassLoader` whenever the user runs your application. You can read more about it in [Accessing Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

Answer (score -1):

I think I came up with a solution, but I am not sure if this is works. I'd appreciate if you would take a look.

```
try {
    File bpdn = new File(getDataFolder() + "badpiggiesdrip.nbs");
    if (!bpdn.exists()) {
        bpdn.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(bpdn);
    fos.write(new byte[] {
            Byte.parseByte(Arrays.toString(Base64.getDecoder().decode(Common.myString)))
    });

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Common.myString is just a string, that contains data of this type:

```
(byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x5a, .....
```

and it's encoded in Base64.

Comment: This works but is not a good solution. Give [enzo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68144726/68587) another look.